# Infinite dimensional convex cone

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> For every infinite set $I$, the closed convex cone $S:=\{f\in \mathbb{R}^{(I)}:f\geq 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{(I)}$, equipped with the finest locally convex topology, has empty interior.

How do I prove that?
Also, is there a specific reason why $I$ in $\mathbb{R}^{(I)}$ is in brackets? Why not just $\mathbb{R}^{I}$?

Comment: Show that for any set of the form $B=\{f | |\phi_k(f)| < \epsilon, k=1,...,n \}$ (where $\phi_k$ are linear functionals on $\mathbb{R}^I$) contains some $g\neq 0$ such that $\lambda g \in B$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you share more details?

Comment: The sets of the form $B$ form a base for the topology. The codimension of $\ker \phi_k$ is one for all $k$ , so $\cap_k \ker \phi_k$ is non trivial and contains a line. This line must violate the cone condition somewhere, hence $S$ contains no open set.